# Javascript .append with fadein?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey how can i append something to a other class with a fadein animation with javascript ?

My try

```
success:function(data){
        $(".new_posts").append(data);
        $(".new_posts").fadeIn();
        }
```

And how can i check in JS when a Textbox is empty ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you try to explain your problem more? What does it mean to 'append' with a 'fadein'?

Comment: .fadeIn is a Function of Javascript to animate or blend in something 
like not booom there is it ... 
like smoooth showing.

Comment: I know what jQuery's `fadeIn` is, but I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Oh i want to add my repsonse form my ajax response to a Div 
but smooth and not hard. 
So my Question is how i can combine append + fadein or something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appendTo() function.

`$('<div style="display:none">Content to append and reveal</div>').appendTo($('#selector')).fadeIn();`

For the input just use

`if ( $('#input-field') ).text() == '') { ... }`

Comment: Thank you very much :)
i get the Div from a Ajax request so i hope it works to with a variable ?

Comment: + It isnt working. 
Appends the Datas but it dont Fade in

Comment: I've set up a jsFiddle. I had it wrong in the original for the input test. You need to use .val() not .text().

Comment: Also, the appendto() and fadein() only works if it has display:none set. If you just hide your jQuery object before appendTo it works. Like this: `myJqueryObject.hide().appendTo( $('#target-div') ).fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

The element that you are appending must be hidden by default.

```
el.append('<div class="hidden">..</div>')
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And because the browser needs to actually append the element before fading it in you should wrap it in `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.hidden').fadeIn()
})
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/jPQvgb)